# Mysql connection string on bigrock server

Tags: asp.net, mysql, hosting

I am trying to connect the mysql(provided by domain provider) with my asp.net 4.0 application on the server.
My connection string is

```
server=71.83.24.256;uid=arrest;pwd=password;database=admin_db1;
```

but i am getting the following error...

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

how can i solve this issue...any ideas??????

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" 
            SortExpression="username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password" 
            SortExpression="password" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is my .cs code

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from [Login]";
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Please post your .NET code where you create the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the wrong provider type, as that is a SQL Server provider error message. You'll need to change the provider to match the provider you need to use for MySQL.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more..i m new to this..or any link to help me out

Comment: i changed the connction string to Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword; still same error

Comment: You are changing the connections tring, not the provider. Please provide the .NET code where you create the connection.

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=100.100.100.46;User ID=root"
        ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Login">

Comment: i changed my connection string and provider as done in above comment...dnt help...same error

Comment: It seems that you need to ask the connection string with your current provider. I belive every provider have their own rule. :)

Comment: i tried asking the provider about the connection string...he said that they don't do coding...but he made a small php code which is working fine...when i used the same credential in my mysql connection string..it didnt work.. my domain is givemyspace.com and givemyspace.com/db.php

Answer (score 0):

The SqlDataSource should use the MySql connector by specifying "ProviderName":

1. Download and install Connector for .Net:
   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
2. Connection string:

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AaaConnectionString" 
        connectionString="database=dbname;server=LOCALHOST;User Id=dba;password=*****"/>
</connectionStrings>`

3. In .aspx:

   `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlTableProcess" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AaaConnectionString%>"
       ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Process ORDER BY DateIssued DESC">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>`